# is their any way to show random forest as nonlinear using suppose 100 attributes

Tags: random-forest

Is their any way to show random forest as nonlinear using suppose 100 attributes.
Actually I compared the accuracy of J48 with Random forest. Random forest works better as given works better for Nonlinear so how to prove or show it.

Answer (score 1):

First a simple proof that RF can capture some non-linear signal:

```
obs=2500
vars = 100
X = data.frame(replicate(vars,runif(obs,-2,2)))
y = apply(X,1,function(x) sum(x^2))
rfo = randomForest(X,y)
print(rfo)
```

As the randomForest can fit the non-linear signal, explained variance 85% ( out-of-bag cross validated) it is hereby empirically shown.

Second you can inspect any curvature of any random forest model with following example:

I use forestFloor package to visualize the RF model trained on a data set sample from the hidden non-linear function:

y = f(x) ={x_1}^2 + sin(x_2) + x_3 * x_4 where X is sampled from a normal distribution. As the found curvature reproduces the non-linear hidden function

```
library(forestFloor)
library(randomForest)
#simulate data
obs=2500
vars = 6 
X = data.frame(replicate(vars,rnorm(obs)))
Y = with(X, X1^2 + sin(X2*pi) + 2 * X3 * X4 + 1 * rnorm(obs))

#grow a forest, remeber to include inbag
rfo=randomForest(X,Y,keep.inbag = TRUE,sampsize=1500,ntree=500)

#compute/extract mapping curvature
ff = forestFloor(rfo,X)

#plot partial functions of most important variables first
plot(ff) 

#Non interacting functions are well displayed, whereas X3 and X4 are not
#by applying different colourgradient, interactions reveal themself 
Col = fcol(ff,3,orderByImportance=FALSE)
plot(ff,col=Col,plot_GOF=TRUE) 

#in 3D the interaction between X3 and X reveals itself completely
show3d(ff,3:4,col=Col,plot.rgl=list(size=5),orderByImportance=FALSE) 

#although no interaction, a joined additive effect of X1 and X2
#colour by FC-component FC1 and FC2 summed
Col = fcol(ff,1:2,orderByImportance=FALSE,X.m=FALSE,RGB=TRUE)
plot(ff,col=Col) 
show3d(ff,1:2,col=Col,plot.rgl=list(size=5),orderByImportance=FALSE) 

#...or two-way gradient is formed from FC-component X1 and X2.
Col = fcol(ff,1:2,orderByImportance=FALSE,X.matrix=TRUE,alpha=0.8) 
plot(ff,col=Col) 
show3d(ff,1:2,col=Col,plot.rgl=list(size=5),orderByImportance=FALSE)
```